# How to change permission on file in Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, sonarqube, dockerfile

I have the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM sonarqube

ADD https://github.com/gabrie-allaigre/sonar-gitlab-plugin/releases/download/4.0.0/sonar-gitlab-plugin-4.0.0.jar /opt/sonarqube/extensions/plugins/
RUN chmod +r /opt/sonarqube/extensions/plugins/ && chown -R sonarqube.sonarqube /opt/sonarqube/extensions/plugins/
```

And I get the following error :

```
Step 3/3 : RUN chmod +x /opt/sonarqube/extensions/plugins/ && chown -R sonarqube.sonarqube /opt/sonarqube/extensions/plugins/
 ---> Running in 0fd0abc88b73
chown: changing ownership of '/opt/sonarqube/extensions/plugins/sonar-gitlab-plugin-4.0.0.jar': Operation not permitted
The command '/bin/sh -c chmod +x /opt/sonarqube/extensions/plugins/ && chown -R sonarqube.sonarqube /opt/sonarqube/extensions/plugins/' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

If I do :

```
FROM sonarqube


ADD https://github.com/gabrie-allaigre/sonar-gitlab-plugin/releases/download/4.0.0/sonar-gitlab-plugin-4.0.0.jar /opt/sonarqube/extensions/plugins/
RUN sudo chmod +r /opt/sonarqube/extensions/plugins/ && sudo chown -R sonarqube.sonarqube /opt/sonarqube/extensions/plugins/
```

I get the following error :

```
Step 3/3 : RUN sudo chmod +x /opt/sonarqube/extensions/plugins/ && sudo chown -R sonarqube.sonarqube /opt/sonarqube/extensions/plugins/
 ---> Running in c7dc030ea2ac
/bin/sh: 1: sudo: not found
The command '/bin/sh -c sudo chmod +x /opt/sonarqube/extensions/plugins/ && sudo chown -R sonarqube.sonarqube /opt/sonarqube/extensions/plugins/' returned a non-zero code: 127
```

How can I change the file's permission in Dockerfile?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`chmod +r /opt/sonarqube/extensions/plugins/` throws an error because the sonarqube container is run as user `sonarqube`(see the `USER sonarqube` command in the Dockerfile: https://github.com/SonarSource/docker-sonarqube/blob/master/7.7-community/Dockerfile)

`sudo` is not installed in the image, so you won't be able to run commands with `sudo`. Instead, as M. Alekseev mentiones, change the user to `root` and run your custom commands.

```
USER root
RUN ...
RUN ...

# switch back to user sonarqube for security
USER sonarqube
```

I'd recommend to switch back to user `sonarqube` after installing your custom packages etc.

Note that you might need to set permissions on files created by the root user then.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using sudo if you want to run command as root user use `USER root` line to switch to root and then execute your commands